# Hiding template arguments in std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a set of template classes that I want to put inside a `std::variant`. The following works, but is rather ugly (I have many more classes in the variant, with many template parameters).

```
template <typename T>
struct Type1
{ };

template <typename B, typename C>
struct Type2
{ };

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
using Variant = std::variant<Type1<A>, Type2<B,C>>;
```

Is it possible to "hide" the template arguments in a similar way to this? (doesn't compile)

```
template <typename A>
using Type1T = Type1<A>

template <typename B, typename C>
using Type2T = Type2<B, C>

using Variant = std::variant<Type1T, Type2T>
```

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list
>   for 'template class std::variant'

Adding `typename` also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `using Type1T = Type1<ExistingA>; using Type2T = Type2<ExisitingB, ExistingC>; using Variant = std::variant<Type1T, Type2T>; ?`

Comment: Do you want your `Variant` generic, or fixed for given types ?

Comment: Then you have a family of `Variant`s, templated over the type parameters.

Comment: Do you want `Variant` to hold *any possible* `Type1` instantiation?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, and every Type2, etc. I need to use Type1/2 inside a visitor

Comment: There are lots of ways to "erase" types, but they depend on details not provided.  As usual with these requests, the general "simple" case basically requires that C++ ship with a full C++ compiler and full source of all code.  Modest restrictions on the request completely change what is required, but because the OP is unfamiliar with type erasure techniques in C++, the OP doesn't even know what would clarify the problem.  In short, your answer is "maybe", but "no as described", and google C++ type erasure and maybe you'll find what you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `std::variant` to do that. You can use `std::any`, but you can't `visit` an `any`.

The problem is that `Type1` and `Type2` *are not* types, they are *type templates*. There is an *infinity* of instantiations of `Type1`, which are all *unrelated types* as far as a `visit` is concerned.

I suggest you make non-template `Type1Base` which you derive `Type1<T>` from, and have a `std::variant<std::unique_ptr<Type1Base>, std::unique_ptr<Type2Base>, ...>`

Edit - even `template_variant` is not possible, there is no way to recover which instantiation of the selected template is the active member. If that were possible, you have the complication that *every* visitor has to have an overload for *every* instantiation of *every* template.

Original attempt:

You could write your own template variant, which would have a mix of members similar to `std::any` and `std::variant`

```
template<template<class...> class ... Templates>
class template_variant
{
    std::any value;
public:
  // constructors, operator=, etc

  // Observers
    constexpr std::size_t index() const noexcept; // Which template this contains
    const std::type_info& type() const noexcept; // returns the typeid of the contained value

 // Modifiers
    template <template<typename...> class T, class... Args>
    T<Args...>& 
    emplace(Args&&... args)
    {
         value.emplace<T<Args...>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <size_t I, class... Args>
    template_variant_alternative_t<I, variant, Args...>& 
    emplace(Args&&... args)
    {
         value.emplace<template_variant_alternative_t<I, variant, Args...>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void swap( template_variant& rhs ) noexcept;

  // Non-member functions
    friend template <std::size_t I, template<class...> class ... Templates, class... Args>
    constexpr template_variant_alternative_t<I, template_variant<Templates...>, Args...>& 
    std::get(template_variant<Templates...>& v)
    {
        try 
        {
            return std::any_cast<template_variant_alternative_t<I, template_variant<Templates...>, Args...>&>(v.value);
        }
        catch (std::bad_any_cast & e)
        {
            throw bad_template_variant_access(e);
        }
    }
    // and &&, and const&, and const&&

    template <template<class...> class T, template<class...> class ... Templates, class... Args>
    constexpr T<Args...>& 
    std::get(template_variant<Templates...>& v)
    {
        try 
        {
            return std::any_cast<T<Args...>&>(v.value);
        }
        catch (std::bad_any_cast & e)
        {
            throw bad_template_variant_access(e);
        }
    }
    // and &&, and const&, and const&&

    // etc.
};

template <std::size_t I, typename Variant, class... Args>
struct template_variant_alternative;

template <std::size_t I, template<class...> class ... Templates, class... Args>
struct template_variant_alternative<I, template_variant<Templates...>, Args...>
{
    using type = // apply Args... to Ith template in Templates
};

template <std::size_t I, typename Variant, class... Args>
using template_variant_alternative_t = template_variant_alternative<I, Variant, Args...>::type;
```